# how do I enable fluxbox instead of Gnome by default in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, fluxbox

I'm working on a VPS which I can control with PuTTY and FreeNX.

I don't have enough RAM for Gnome, so I want fluxbox to start by default instead of Gnome. how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to create a custom session , which launches fluxbox

Create a file e.g `/usr/share/xsessions/custom.desktop`

Which contains:

```
Name=Xsession
Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Change that (Exec=) to your customized script  , e.g if you favors `xinit` , you can edit ~/.xinitrc , place a `startfluxbox` there (IIRC)

And in that case , the `Exec=` script would be `/usr/bin/startx`